# Browsing Java comments in Eclipse in an easy way

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

In a large project I need to review all the code comments and so I'm searching for something in Eclipse to browse comments in an easy way (Javadoc comments principally). Is it possible that doesn't exist a view or something else in Eclipse to do this?

I am sure it exists so please suggest me the tips :)

thanks a lot

rob

Comment: I need to review comments to be sure that the form of the comment is right. So I don't want to navigate into the code logic, I would need only a view with a list of comments. Yes, I can do it with a search...but I'd hope in something more advanced :)

Answer (score 3):

Just generate the javadoc and go from there, I think that would make a lot more sense

Comment: mhhh, see my comment to the original question. I'd like a unique vew in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

For browsing there is a view:

```
Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Java -> Javadoc
```

If you select a class / field / method in the Project Explorer it will show up in the Javadoc view.

For searching try a file search with file name pattern set to *.java.

```
Search -> File...
```